# Add current or next year to string depending on month

Tags: python

I am scraping from https://stocktwits.com/SpeedyCalls and need to format the dates the bot uses for expiration such that it has the correct expiration year appended to the end.

And example is below. The December ones would be this current year, the Jan and beyond would be next year.

I could figure out a hack but I'm sure you smarter people would be able to figure out a more accurate and correct way.
Thanks.

```
'Jan, 19th'
'Dec, 15th'
'Jan, 19th'
'Jun, 15th'
'Apr, 20th'
'Dec, 15th'
'Jan, 19th'
'Dec, 15th'
'Jan, 19th'
'Feb, 16th'
'May, 18th'
'Dec, 15th'
'Mar, 16th'
'Dec, 15th'
'Feb, 16th'
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I was planning on appending both to each and determine which of the two is between datetime.now() and datetime.now()+timedelta('182 days')

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I wrote to solve the need.

```
def get_exp_date(self, exp):
    exp_datetime_0 = datetime.strptime(exp+str(datetime.now().year), '%b, %d %Y')
    exp_datetime_1 = datetime.strptime(exp+str(datetime.now().year+1), '%b, %d %Y')
    start = datetime.now()
    end = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=182)

    if exp_datetime_1<end and exp_datetime_1>start:
        exp_date = exp_datetime_1
    else:
        exp_date = exp_datetime_0

    return exp_date.strftime('%b, %d %Y')
```